# Using google map api (or fusion) to make a Customized Deprivation map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-fusion-tables, fusion

I am trying to make a deprivation map using google map. My data contains an array of 2 elements - 'a deprivation value' at a location 'postcode'. All I need to do is to draw a color (darker = more deprivation) on the postcode area. This seems to be easy to implement using Fusion table.

However, the postcode I have is either 7 or 8 characters long (eg AB1 1WA). However, the 'UK Regional KML Boundaries' data I found on google seems to contain the first 3 or 4 letters. In the above example, it will be 'AB1 1'. My question is how do I convert my original postcodes (7/8 letters) to the new format (3/4 letters)?

I could do it manually first (or write a seperate program) and then copy it to fusion table. But can I possibly write a javascript program to do it? How can the fusion table works together with customized javascript program?

Comment: Your question title is misleading; it's not "Using google map api (or fusion) to make a Customized Deprivation map", it should be "how do I get the first 3-4 characters from UK postcodes"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I really want to ask is if using fusion is the best way to implement a customized map with data? If I also want some animations, say when the page is loaded, i want to show deprivation profiles for 3 cities, London, Birmingham and Manchester, then allow users to use the map. Do I need to write some javascript to do this?